# AppleScript: How to get all window names of processes that share the same title?

Tags: applescript, macos

The process, `RSScriptRunner`, represents a currently running script that was triggered by FastScripts.app. (FastScripts does not assign unique process titles to scripts that it triggers.)

If one has multiple processes titled `RSScriptRunner` running simultaneously, then the following code:

```
tell application "System Events" to windows of process "RSScriptRunner"
```

will only return the window name of the process that began the earliest.

However, I would like to get every window name of every `RSScriptRunner` process.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this in AppleScript?

---

My ultimate intent here is to implement a check that ensures that only one instance of one script can run simultaneously. Multiple different scripts running is okay, but multiples of a script running at the same time is undesirable.

The code would look something like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theWindowList to windows of process "RSScriptRunner"
    if theWindowList contains "The title of the initial dialog of this script goes here." then
        error number -128
    end if
end tell
```

This check would be located at the very top of the script.

---

Note:

This is very much a situation where minimal latency is crucial.

I had devised a long-winded method that successfully realized my desired outcome. The method entailed getting every current process title into one list, and getting every current process ID into another, corresponding list. I then retrieved the window name of each `RSScriptRunner` process via its respective process ID (which, unlike the process name, must be unique).

However, this method brought with it a couple seconds of latency. I need a solution that is nearly instant (such as, the line of code above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: On my system, **macOS Sierra**, there is no window for this process.

You can use a **whose** clause, like this:

For a process that contains only one window, use this script:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theWindowList to name of window 1 of (processes whose name is "RSScriptRunner")
    if theWindowList contains "The title of the initial dialog of this script goes here." then
        error number -128
    end if
end tell
```

---

For a process that can contain one or more windows, use this script:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set myList to name of windows of (processes whose name is "RSScriptRunner") -- get a list of lists, each sublist contains names 
end tell
set theWindowList to my subListsToOneList(myList) --  Flattening a list of lists

if theWindowList contains "The title of the initial dialog of this script goes here." then
    error number -128
end if

on subListsToOneList(l)
    set newL to {}
    repeat with i in l
        set newL to newL & i
    end repeat
    return newL
end subListsToOneList
```

---

The solution for **macOS Sierra**, maybe it works for other **OSes** as well, to get the name of the launched scripts, is to use the `ps` and `pgrep` commands.

```
set theNameList to paragraphs of (do shell script "ps -p $(pgrep -x RSScriptRunner) | sed -n 's:.*RSScriptRunner.*/::p'") -- get the name of the scripts
if theNameList contains "the name of this script.scpt" then error number -128
```

*Informations*:

- `$(pgrep -x RSScriptRunner)` : A sub shell to get the process ID of
  each instance of the **RSScriptRunner**, the '-x' option: require
  an exact match of the process name
- `ps -p`: get the command of each PID (the result contains the path of
  the launched script).
- The `sed` command : delete characters from the beginning of the line
  through the last slash character to get the name of the script (the
  `-n`option is to print the line which contains the
  '**RSScriptRunner**' word only, because the first line is the headers
  --> `PID TTY           TIME CMD`).

Comment: Your first solution works perfectly. Regarding the second solution (i.e., the third code block in your answer), I had to change `if theNameList contains "name.scpt" then` to `if item 1 of theNameList contains "name.scpt" then` in order to get it to work on El Capitan (10.11.6), but this solution works perfectly, as well. Thank you for the solutions!

Comment: In my previous comment, I was mistaken. Your second solution works perfectly on 10.11.6 - without any modification whatsoever.